# whas is diffrence of in-line and out-line call mehtod in dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc

I used this method in my Bloc in two types

first:

```
 on<MyEvent>(
      (event, emit) async {
        var datastate =
            await _productUsecase.getCategories();
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            categories: datastate,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

and this :

```
on<MyEvent>(
      (event, emit) async {
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            categories: await _productUsecase.getCategories(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

but they change my app in two ways.
why?

Comment: What do you mean with "they change my app in two ways"?

Comment: the state of bloc is not equal when i run these codes every time. "await _productUsecase.getCategories()" fetch a list and then i set it in state, but my state have some other varables, that will change by other events, the second code work worng.

Answer (score 0):

i found the mistake,
its about scopes, my first code is await out side of copyWith, and after fetch data it set it in state and then emit
but, in the 2end one it await in CopyWith method, this cause to during await , save state variable and copyWith method will set this fetched data to state of befor await, and may be during fetching , it change with other events.